# Play framework : UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LVEnhancer

Tags: java, playframework, ubuntu-14.04

I am using for the first time Play framework, on Ubuntu 14, with an existing project. When I try to run the application, I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /

Oops: UnexpectedException
Unexpected error : While applying play.CorePlugin@44821a96 on models.BookingDTO, caused by exception UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LVEnhancer on models.BookingDTO

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@44821a96 on models.BookingDTO
   at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:582)
   at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:242)
   at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:164)
   at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:431)
   at play.Play.start(Play.java:527)
   at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:647)
   at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:205)
   at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LVEnhancer on models.BookingDTO
   at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:314)
   at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:577)
   ... 7 more
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: LVEnhancer: cannot enhance the behavior 'models.BookingDTO.findAllNextBookings(java.lang.String)'
   at play.classloading.enhancers.LVEnhancer.enhanceThisClass(LVEnhancer.java:112)
   at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:309)
   ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at bytecodeparser.CodeParser.parse(CodeParser.java:53)
   at bytecodeparser.analysis.stack.StackAnalyzer.init(StackAnalyzer.java:91)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You got a NullPointerException ;) But seriously we need more information. What program were you running? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your answer.

I found the solution : I didn't have the version of **javassist** that didin't match with the project files.

With the **Playframework 1.3**, javassist-3.20xxx didn't work. I had to install  **javassist-3.19xxx**